# Echo XML node CDATA using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, cdata

I have an XML file in this format:

```
            <definitions>
              <group name="skin">
                <string name="string_name"><![CDATA[String Name]]></string>
              </group>
            </definitions>
```

I can't figure out how to get the string name to output by going down through definitions>group>string, is it possible to select by the string name="xxx" or only string?

```
            <?php
                if (file_exists('definitions.xml')) {
                    $xml = simplexml_load_file('definitions.xml');
                    echo (string) $xml->string;
                } else {
                    exit('Failed to open');
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct syntax to access the `string` node; `$xml` is equivalent to the top node, `definitions`, so you need to access `$xml->group->string` to get the contents of the `string` node:

```
echo (string)$xml->group->string;
```

Output:

```
String Name
```

FYI, you can print the node contents without casting it as a string:

```
echo $xml->group->string;
```